# Python autocomplete for methods in SublimeText editor (problems with parentheses)

Tags: python, methods, autocomplete, sublimetext3, parentheses

I'm a newbie with Sublime and Python development. Could some one help me to find option where I can turn on autocomplete for methods in Python in Sublime?

Problem is that I need to type parentheses after methods manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**anaconda**](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/#carousel-features)

[image]

For installing, Just run

`git clone https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda`

inside your packages directory to install from git

Comment: Anaconda do not work as well. I always got this problem: <Anaconda.anaconda_lib.workers.local_worker.LocalWorker object at 0x10c631950> initial check failed because:

can not connect to localhost in port 64039. tried to connect 21 times during 2 seconds

check that there is Python process executing the anaconda jsonserver.py script running in your system. If there is, check that you can connect to your localhost writing the following script in your Sublime Text 3 console:

import socket; socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect(("localhost", 64039))

Comment: @AndreyMarchenko Anaconda works well :) read this for solving your problem https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/issues/527